# How should I let my python and rails http servers communicate securely

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api-auth

I was building an app where I want my Python application to securely communicate with my Rails application and send it some data. I'm more inclined to use HTTP to get them to communicate.

I came across this gem ([Api Auth](https://github.com/mgomes/api_auth)), but it seems to only work for Ruby app to Ruby app.

Comment: Definitely HTTPS. Both servers should be set up with SSL certificates. Then add some code to each app that will whitelist which IP addresses or domain names are allowed to make requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about 2 solutions

1. IP address of each application added to white list for the other application so it only accepts requests for some endpoints from the IP address of the other application
2. May be you can implement it yourself by implementing an endpoint for generating a token and save it in database and then authorize only requests that contain the correct token in the header "_token"

But I vote for the first one because as you said you have only 2 applications so you don't need to complicate stuff. 
The second solution is used in use cases like Facebook apps where every developer register an application and have a secret key generated for his application where it's used for all requests of his application